# can activate trigger when last record entered to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

am new to triggers ,
i have 3 tables 
bill table for the main data of bill
billITem table for items listed in bill
BillSerialNb table for serial numbers related to items listed in bill

i need a trigger to compare the entered billItem qty with serialNmb related to these billItems 
if serialNb not equal to BillItem qty i should raise an error and return .

The idea that if trigger done after insert or update on BillSerialNb table , it is being fired on each single record entered to BillSerialNb table and am not able to do the right counting of serial number entered , can i catch the whole rows that will enter the table ?!

is there a solution ?

Comment: Yes you can. Specify your RDBMS.

Comment: am working on sql server 2008

Comment: Please post sample data and desired outcome.  Your question is unclear without it.